# MFC and OpenGL events for drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, point-clouds

I have built a SDI MFC application, where the CView child is drawing a cube with OpenGL. This cube is drawn by the following function:

```
void CglSDI3View::setupScene()
{

wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);

// Clear color and depth buffer bits
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Wireframe Mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// Front Side
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

// Back Side
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

// Top Side

(...)

glEnd();

SwapBuffers(m_hDC);


}
```

I have no Timer defined. Rigth now, my `OnDraw` function is as follows:

```
void CglSDI3View::OnDraw(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
CglSDI3Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();

wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);

glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -m_fZoom);
glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
glRotatef(m_fRotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(m_fRotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

setupScene();

wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

ValidateRect(NULL);
}
```

where `m_fRotX`, `m_fRotY`, `m_fPosX`, etc. are scaling and translation factors. My question is: do I need to call `setupScene()` on every `OnDraw()` call? Or can this be optimized? In other words, does the cube have to be redrawn on every `OnDraw()` call or is there a way to do this only once and then apply only transformations?

Please note that in the future, the `setupScene()` function will draw a huge point cloud with millions of colored points, so this needs to be optimized as much as possible.

Comment: You could use the OpenGL's VBO mechanism maybe?

Comment: @TheRealNox: No you can't because VBOs are just hunks of memory managed by OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

The name "setupScene" is misleading. OpenGL has no scenes. OpenGL has no models. OpenGL is not a scene graph.

*OpenGL is a "dumb" drawing API. It draws points, lines and triangles, one at a time. And after drawing something it already forgets about it.*

So yes, you have to redraw if you want to have some changes in the drawing to happen, because, well, it's just a drawing and nothing more. There's no retained scene OpenGL could manipulate.

So rename "setupScene" to "drawScene" and use it as the thereby apt name suggests.